# WPF datagrid is not displaying result in one row?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Hi i am working with wpf application ,there is a datagrid in which i am displaying my result after extracting piece of string.The problem is data is displaying in a grid in two but i want it on single row.Code is :

C#

```
public ObservableCollection<IPMAC> ipmac { get; set; }



public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ipmac = new ObservableCollection<IPMAC>();
            this.DataContext = this;


        }

 string pattern = @"(F8-F7-D3-00\S+)";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(stringData, pattern);

            string pattern2 = @"(192.168.1\S+)";
            MatchCollection matchesIP = Regex.Matches(stringData, pattern2);



            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hardware Address : {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
                ipmac.Add(new IPMAC() { mac = match.Groups[1].Value });

            }


            foreach (Match match in matchesIP)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IP Address : {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
                ipmac.Add(new IPMAC() { ip = match.Groups[1].Value });

            }
        }
        private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dg.ItemsSource = ipmac;
        }
```

XAML:

```
![<DataGrid
                  Name="dg"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  Height="250"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ipmac}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"            

                  IsReadOnly="True"
            >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mac Addresses" Binding="{Binding Path=mac}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP Addresses" Binding="{Binding Path=ip}"/>


            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>][1]
```

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to show result in one row .Any help would be highly appreciable??

Comment: Since you have two results it displays two rows!

Comment: You are adding (at least) two IPMAC to the collection, so yes, it will be displayed in two rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your parsing to something like this:

```
var item = new IPMAC();
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
      Console.WriteLine("Hardware Address : {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
      item.mac = match.Groups[1].Value;
}


foreach (Match match in matchesIP)
{
      Console.WriteLine("IP Address : {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
      item.ip = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
ipmac.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        //Create your Obj Outside
        IPMAC ipObj = new IPMAC();
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hardware Address : {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
            ipObj.mac = match.Groups[1].Value;

        }   
        foreach (Match match in matchesIP)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IP Address : {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
            ipObj.ip = match.Groups[1].Value;

        }
        ipmac.Add(ipObj);

       private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
        dg.ItemsSource = ipmac;
       }
```